# How does a calculator calculate binomial coefficients for large $n$?

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, calculator

I've got an interesting puzzle. I'm playing around on a Casio fx-991EX and I notice it has a binomial distribution function. Trying to see how large of a value of $n$ it could take, thinking that in the guts of the computer it was translating my query into factorials and calculating it that way, I put in values of $n$ such that $n>1000$. To my surprise, the binomial function has no issues taking these extremely large values of $n$ (way larger than the factorial or $^n C_r$ functions can take).

I imagine within the calculator is some in built condition that forces it to instead calculate an approximation using the normal function. Does anybody know if this is true/if not, how it calculates it?

Comment: I don't know precisely what method is used, but calculating the factorials and combinatorics terms is much easer in $\log$ scale. $\log{{n}\choose k} = \log (n!) - \log(k!) - \log((n-k)!) = \sum_{j=k+1}^n\log(j) - \sum_{j = 1}^k\log(j)$

Comment: It could also, for large $n$ be using Stirling's formula for $n!$

Comment: It can also simplify the factorials, for example $^{2000}C_4=\frac{2000\cdot 1999 \cdot 1998 \cdot 1997}{4!}$ which avoids huge numbers.

Comment: You are talking about this: https://edu.casio.com/support/qsg/pdf/991EX_570EX/06_CASIO_QuickStartGuide_fx-991EX_fx-570EX_DISTRIBUTION.pdf -- is that correct? So you are looking at a function of three variables ($n$, $x$, $p$) and not just two variables, and the value of the function is the binomial coefficient $\binom nx = {}^nC_x$ multiplied by other terms that depend on $n$, $x$, and $p$, the final value being between $0$ and $1.$

Comment: @RossMillikan true, but if you have a binomial calculation which would use a $^n C_r$ calculation that would itself give a math error, the binomial distribution function can still calculate it meaning that it mustn't be actually evaluating these terms.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, I agree. Though I wonder how this is implemented as any $^nC_r \sim 10^{100}$ mustn't be evaluated directly as that would spit out a math error. e.g. if you attempted $\frac{10^{100}}{10^{99}}$ this would spit out a math error even though evaluated this is only 10.

Comment: Binomial coefficients can be easily computed (with a reasonable number of computations and no explosions) via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula and you can easily work in powers of $p$ if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Even by hand, you can have good *approximations*
$$\binom{n}{m}=\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (m+1)\,\,\Gamma (n+1-m)}$$ Let $m=kn$ ($k\leq \frac 12$), take logarithms, use three times Stirling approximation for large $n$ and finish using Taylor series to obtain
$$\log \left(\binom{n}{k n}\right)=\left((k-1)\log(1-k)-k\log(k)\right)\,n+$$
$$-\frac 12 \log (2 \pi  (1-k) k\, n)+\frac{k^2-k+1}{12 (k-1) k\,n}+\frac{-k^6+3 k^5-3 k^4+k^3-3 k^2+3 k-1}{360 (k-1)^3 k^3\,n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ and exponentiate the result.

Trying for $n=123456$ and $m=7890$ this would give
$$\color{red}{2.7434922768176718837476}817\times 10^{12736}$$ instead of
$$2.7434922768176718837476105\times 10^{12736}$$

Comment: Interesting. I wonder what approximation the calculator is implementing to calculate this?